# Why do Windows 7 and 8 often not update open folders after adding or renaming files or subfolders?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

Three scenarios:

- I right click in a folder and choose "new folder".
- Windows does not show me the new subfolder, as would be expected. To get Windows to actually show me the subfolder I just created, I have to manually refresh, at which point the new subfolder will appear with the default "New folder" name. (If I at this point attempt to rename the new folder, I'll often have to refresh *again* to make Windows show me the updated name, see below.)

Or:

- I rename a file or folder.
- Once I press enter, Windows continues to display the old name until I manually refresh the folder.

Or:

- I copy one or more files into a folder.
- None of the files actually appear until I manually refresh the folder.

This happens *all* the time in Windows 7 and 8, and is quite the annoyance. As far as I can remember, nothing like this ever happened while I used Windows XP. Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Comment: I think this is the reverse situation. My windows XP PC at the company never refreshes the folder after copying, renaming or anything like that. While my windows 7 and 8 PCs automatically do that everytime there's a change in the folder

Comment: I cannot replicate that, only differance I have seen is the hop sorting it into the alphabetical order (or not).  Can I ask what View mode your using at the time?  Icons lists or thumbnails? What column sort method is applied at the time?  Is it local storage?  or better what is the storage item?  Are they "links" or in the library, or is this in a normal folder made by you right on the real drive.

Comment: Thanks, @and31415, this does appear to be the same problem. Unfortunately, it appears there is no clear solution to the problem.